# How can I effectively use jmeter test to run every hour for monitoring?

Tags: jmeter

I have written jmeter script. Now I want to use that for monitoring purposes. I know that there are some monitoring tools available like Datadog etc. for API monitoring but those are quite expensive. I am looking for a cheap solution that fulfills my purpose. Can someone please help? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The fastest and the easiest way is just going for [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMon/) which can collect [> 70 various metrics](https://github.com/undera/perfmon-agent/blob/master/README.md#supported-metrics) and save them into .csv file and/or plot the chart(s).

If this is something which is sufficient for you check out [How to Monitor Your Server Health & Performance During a JMeter Load Test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-performance-metrics) for more details.

In case if you're still looking for Datadog-like experience you will need to choose an APM tool, there are several which are free and open source including but not limited to:

- [Apache SkyWalking](https://skywalking.apache.org/)
- [PinPoint](https://github.com/pinpoint-apm/pinpoint#about-pinpoint)
- [Scouter](https://github.com/scouter-project/scouter#application-performance-monitoring-for-open-source-sws)